# How to get File extension while retriving saved Files from MS SQL Server2008 to local drive

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am in such a circumstance where I want to save and retrieve all types of files in MS SQL SERVER 2008, I can Save and retrieve any file but without extension, For example if I saves xyz.txt file into database, when I retrieve it on local drive it looks like xyz , no extension, and yes if we give extension manually then we can see its contents.

Following is my table image
[image: Table]

C# code for saving any file type to database

```
 private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Read File Bytes into a byte array
            byte[] FileData = ReadFile(txtFilePath.Text);

            //Initialize SQL Server Connection
            SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);

            //Set insert query
            string qry = "insert into FilesStore (OriginalPath,FileData) values(@OriginalPath, @FileData)";

            //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, CN);

            //We are passing Original File Path and File byte data as sql parameters.
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)txtFilePath.Text));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileData", (object)FileData));

            //Open connection and execute insert query.
            CN.Open();
            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CN.Close();

            //Close form and return to list or Files.
            this.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

C# code for retrieving file from database to local drive

```
private void btnSaveFromDBToDisk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             //Check if a file is selected in Grid
             if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell ==null)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Select a file in Grid first.");
                 return;
             }

             int SelectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
             string OriginalPath = DS.Tables[0].Rows[SelectedRow]["OriginalPath"].ToString();

             saveFileDialog1.FileName = OriginalPath;

             DialogResult DR = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
             if (DR == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                 string FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                 //Get File data from dataset row.
                 byte[] FileData = (byte[])DS.Tables["FilesStore"].Rows[SelectedRow]["FileData"];
                 //Write file data to selected file.
                 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create))
                 {
                     fs.Write(FileData, 0, FileData.Length);
                     fs.Close();
                 }

                 MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully to ");
             }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }
    }
```

Image of how this project works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqYMe.jpg

[image: Save and retrieve image project, unable to see file extension as in step 6 arrow]

You can download this project from here http://www.shabdar.org/sql-server/121-store-or-save-files-in-sql-server-database-using-c.html

Comment: What is the system's setting for "extensions for known file types"? Go to Windows Explorer, press Alt, Select "Tools|Folder Options", select "View" tab, and is "Hide extensions for known file types" ticked? If so, untick it and click "OK".

Comment: Thanx, I checked my system setting as you said, And whooaa I got file extension.. Could you please post this comment in answer so I can mark it as "Answer"

Comment: Done. This has happened to me as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the system's setting for "extensions for known file types"?

Go to Windows Explorer, press Alt, Select "Tools|Folder Options", select "View" tab, and is "Hide extensions for known file types" ticked? If so, untick it and click "OK".

If that was the issue, all should now be ok! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you store your original File-Path in he Database, then simple use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName("")` to get your filename **with** extension. Then
you can creata a new path on your machine where you want to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension()` to get extension of a file:

```
string fileName = @"C:\a\b\c\test.mp3";
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```